# Multiplos Carousel na mesma página

Tags: jquery, css, html5, twitter-bootstrap

Ao inserir multiplos Carousel , ao clicar em qualquer outro carousel, apenas o primeiro muda.

Alguem pode me ajudar?

```
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h3>Titulo nivel 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <!-- CAROUSEL-->    
                 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                         <div class="item active">
                            <img src="" alt="Chania">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 1. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="" alt="Chania">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Header of Slide 2</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 2. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="" alt="Flower">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Header of Slide3</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 3. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
                        <!-- << Controladores >> -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                        <!-- Indicadores  0 0 0-->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                <!--FIM CAROUSEL  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
            <!-- CAROUSEL-->    
                 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                         <div class="item active">
                            <img src="" alt="Chania">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 1. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="" alt="Chania">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Header of Slide 2</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 2. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="" alt="Flower">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Header of Slide3</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 3. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
                        <!-- << Controladores >> -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                        <!-- Indicadores  0 0 0-->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                <!--FIM CAROUSEL  -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h3>Titulo nivel 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h3>Titulo nivel 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

        </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
            <!-- CAROUSEL-->    
                 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                         <div class="item active">
                            <img src="" alt="Chania">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 1. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="" alt="Chania">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Header of Slide 2</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 2. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="" alt="Flower">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Header of Slide3</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 3. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
                        <!-- << Controladores >> -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                        <!-- Indicadores  0 0 0-->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                <!--FIM CAROUSEL  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section>
    <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
            <!-- CAROUSEL-->    
                 <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                         <div class="item active">
                            <img src="" alt="Chania">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 1. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="" alt="Chania">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Header of Slide 2</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 2. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="item">
                            <img src="" alt="Flower">
                            <div class="carousel-caption">
                                <h3>Header of Slide3</h3>
                                <p>Details of Slide 3. Lorem Ipsum Blah Blah Blah....</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                 </div>
                        <!-- << Controladores >> -->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="fa fa-angle-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Ant</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="fa fa-angle-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Prx</span>
                        </a>
                        <!-- Indicadores  0 0 0-->
                        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                            <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                <!--FIM CAROUSEL  -->
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <h3>Titulo nivel 3</h3>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
            tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
            quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
            consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
            cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
            proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Por favor poste seu código javascript (jQuery) que faz a mudança no carousel para que possamos analisar. Provavelmente está sendo feita a modificação por ID ou pelo primeiro elemento com a classe "carousel".

Comment: O problema provavelmente está no `id` que você está utilizando. Pelo que vi no exp de `html` que está utilizando, todos elementos tem o mesmo `id`, `id` é um atributo único que o `DOM` enxerga, quando referencia ele pelo `jquery` ou `javascript`, ele pega apenas o primeiro elemento que ele encontra

Comment: Eu mesmo consegui resolver.. .Falta de atenção minha.. realmente era o ID ! obrigado mesmo assim!